# Как правильно соединить 2 виртуальные машины?

Tags: сеть, virtualbox, виртуальная-машина, virtual-hosts

Имеются 2 виртуальные машины в Oracle VM VirtualBox: Ubuntu и Windows 7. Понадобилось получить доступ к БД PostgreSQL, находящейся на убунту с Windows 7. Искал как подключиться, обнаружил, что обе виртуальные машины имеют одинаковый IP (в настройках стоит NAT). Искал решения на разных сайтах, узнал, что нужно использовать виртуальный адаптер хоста, но так и не понял, как правильно настроить. Если кто-то сможет подсказать, буду благодарен.

В данный момент обе виртуалки подключены через NAT и имеют IP 10.0.2.15.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел сам ответ на свой вопрос, может быть кому-нибудь пригодится. Включаем на обоих виртуальных машинах виртуальные адаптеры. Вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смотрим, что получилось:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сети 10.0.X.X - NAT, нас интересуют адаптеры с сетями 192.168.X.X.

Проверяем подключение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]